# Unique non trivial ideal in CFM(k)

Tags: ring-theory

Given CFM(k), the ring of infinite matrices with finite columns, I've already proved that the subset of matrices with a finite number of rows no null  is an ideal.

How can I prove the following statement?:
CFM(k) have a unique non trivial ideal.

Comment: Are you talking about left, right or two-sided ideals? I understand $\operatorname{CFM}(k)=\{(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^\infty\mid \exists m\colon\forall i,j\colon j>m\to a_{i,j}=0\}$?

Comment: Or rather $\operatorname{CFM}(k)=\{(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^\infty\mid \forall j\colon\exists m\colon\forall i\colon i>m\to a_{i,j}=0\}$?

Comment: This is odd. Both asker and answerer have removed their accounts.

Comment: Column finite matrix rings over very large index sets *can* have more ideals than just three. We can only guess in this case the user is thinking of the countable index-set case, where there are only three ideals.

Answer (score 1):

We are considering the ring
$$R=\operatorname{CFM}(k)=\{(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^\infty\mid \forall j\colon\exists m\colon\forall i\colon i>m\to a_{i,j}=0\}$$
and ideal
$$ \mathfrak a=\{(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^\infty\in R\mid \exists m\colon\forall j\colon\forall i\colon i>m\to a_{i,j}=0\}.$$
Let $\mathfrak b$ be a nontrivial ideal and $B=(b_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^\infty\in\mathfrak b$ a nonzero element, say $b_{i_0,j_0}\ne 0$.
Let $E_{k,l}\in R$ be the matrix with $e_{k,l}=1$ and $0$ otherwise.
Then for all $k,l$ $$E_{k,l}=\frac1{b_{i_0,j_0}}E_{k,i_0}BE_{j_0,l}\in RBR\subseteq \mathfrak b.$$
If $A\in\mathfrak a$ and $a_{i,j}=0$ for all $i>m$ then we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^m E_{k,k}A=A$$
and hence $\mathfrak a\subseteq \mathfrak b$.

Now assume $\mathfrak a\ne\mathfrak b$ and let $B=(b_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^\infty\in\mathfrak b\setminus \mathfrak a$.
For $j\in\mathbb N$ let $m(j)=\min\{m\in\mathbb N_0\mid \forall i>m\colon a_{i,j}=0\}$. Because $B\notin\mathfrak a$, we can find an infinite sequence $j_1, j_2, j_3,\ldots$ such that $1<m(j_1)<m(j_2)<m(j_3)<\ldots$.
The infinite sums
$$ M_1:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{b_{m(j_k),j_k}}E_{k,m(j_k)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad M_2:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{j_k,k}$$
are elements of $R$ because the sums are in fact finite per column.
Then 
$$ M_1 B M_2\in \mathfrak b$$
is an upper triangular matrix with unit diagonal.
To turn this into the infinite identity matrix $I$, takes only row operations, that is left multiplication with another upper triangular matrix, i.e. an element of $R$.
We conclude $I\in\mathfrak b$ and hence $\mathfrak b=R$.

In summary, the only ideal of $R$ are $0$, $\mathfrak a$ and $R$.